# A category theoretical way to describe functions within the category of relations?

Tags: category-theory

I just thought of this question, and a quick wiki search did not turn up anything.

So, here is the question: Rel is the category whose objects are sets, and whose morphisms are binary relations. Is there a way to differentiate between morphisms that are functions and morphisms that aren't using purely category theoretical means (that is, not using the set structure whatsoever).

Followup question: If the answer turns out to be yes, let's call a generic morphism that follows the definition an f-morphism (for function). What are the f-morphisms in other, more commonly used categories, like Set, Top, Grp, Ring, etc.? What are the co-f-morphisms (i.e. morphisms defined dually to f-morphisms)?

Note that I have not yet given the question serious thought, so it may be extremely difficult or extremely easy to answer.

Comment: If **Rel** is treated as a $2$-category using the natural inclusion order on binary relations, then the functions are exactly the binary relations that are left adjoints (and then the right adjoint is necessarily given by the inverse relation).

Comment: I had to look up what a 2-category was, and I think I do intuitively understand how the left and right adjoints would correspond to functions and their inverses (even if it would take me a bit of time to actually prove). I do however wonder if a 1-category definition is possible, or if the partial order structure of the morphisms is 100% nessesary to costruct the definition?